# Apple TV and WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview, tvos, apple-tv

Can we develop the app for Apple TV using the HTML5 inside the web view component ([WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)) or is there any other way to run HTML5 apps or we need to use Swift and build the native app?

Thanks a lot

Petr

Comment: You have to build a native app. It doesn't need to be in Swift

Comment: @Paulw11 Is that some Apple policy that requires native apps? Any reference to that? If you say "It doesn't need to be in Swift" what the other options are? Objective-C?

Comment: There aren't any web views for tvOS. You can also use Xamarin (C#) or React Native and possibly others

Comment: @Paulw11 Understand thanks

Comment: My conclusion on that is that Apple simply does not want the HTML5 apps whatever reasons they have: https://www.it-swarm-fr.com/fr/javascript/application-web-dans-tvos/1055632142/ https://medium.com/bpxl-craft/apple-tv-a-world-without-webkit-5c428a64a6dd. And even there might be workarounds, those are not suitable for commercial App store apps.

Comment: I think Apple have always been pretty clear that they don't really want html5 apps on any of their non-Mac platforms.  They work on iOS because there is a web environment, but they don't go out of their way to support them in the same way that they are supported on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this project:

https://github.com/Moballo-LLC/tvOS-Browser

It's an objective-c project and uses UIWebView but it's working on Apple TV and you can run HTML5.